# SQL in Matlab: Doesn´t recognize variables

Tags: sql, matlab

i have a query in Matlab with variables setting a date and an intervall:

```
WindowSize=60;
Day=1;
Month=1;
Year=2005;
ConstituentDate=datestr(datetime(Year,Month,Day),'mm/dd/yyyy');

% My query:
query='SELECT Preis.Isin,  Preis.Datum,  Preis.Preis FROM (SELECT Preis.Isin AS myISIN FROM Constituents INNER JOIN Preis ON Constituents.Isin = Preis.Isin WHERE (Preis.Datum=(select min(Datum) from Preis  WHERE Datum between DateAdd("m",-', num2str(WindowSize) ', #' ConstituentDate '#) and DateAdd("m",-' num2str(WindowSize-1) ', #' ConstituentDate '#)) AND (Constituents.Datum=#' ConstituentDate '#))) AS AvailableISIN INNER JOIN Preis ON AvailableISIN.myISIN = Preis.Isin WHERE (Preis.Datum IN (SELECT max(Preis.Datum) FROM Preis WHERE (Preis.Datum>=DateAdd("m",-' num2str(WindowSize+1) ', #' ConstituentDate '#) AND (Preis.Datum<#' ConstituentDate '#)) GROUP BY MONTH(Preis.Datum), YEAR(Preis.Datum))) ORDER BY  Preis.Datum,Preis.ISIN';
```

Now i´m wondering why Matlab shows an error on my first variable in query (`num2str(WindowSize)`):

```
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it: I have to use [  ... ]: `[' Select... '];`